# If $\displaystyle x= \frac{e^{3z}}{y^4}$ then $z(x,y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\displaystyle x= \frac{e^{3z}}{y^4}$ then $z(x,y)$ ?

I know that we subtract powers in fractions but how do we solve it when there is a variable $3z$? And what is what is $z(x,y)$?

This question is supposed to be easy and it irritate me that I can't solve it. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you advance

> $$  e^{3z}= xy^4  \implies z=\frac{1}{3} \ln(x y^4). $$

Answer (score 2):

It seems like they are asking for $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.  That is what $z(x,y)$ means.  (It's not entirely clear from just what you've posted, but that would be my best guess.)

So you need to solve for $z$.  First multiply by $y^4$, then take the natural log, then divide by 3.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for editing my question.

Comment: @user89666 you're welcome!